# Send file and json to restfull API sinatra

Tags: ruby, json, api, sinatra, multipart

My sinatra needs to handle json metadatas and a file in a same request.

For that I use multipart :

server side :

```
data = request.params["data"]
file = request.params["myfile"]
```

and it works with curl :
curl -X POST url -F myfile=@file -F data="{\"key\": \"value\"}"

My problem :

Those params are fields but my client (other langages) doesn't have forms so how to separate params without fields (i think i did'nt understand how http works).

Comment: How does your client want to make the call then?

Comment: By creating form on the fly? I'm not sure... Is there an other mean to receive a file and json (or text) with one request? It's a restfull API without user interface.

Comment: Well you said that *my client doesn't have forms* - what does that mean?

Comment: Ah sorry, I wanted to say graphic interface. So is that coherent for the client to create forms in order to communicate with an api? how the form is formatted in the http request (text, xml, html..)?

Comment: It should be possible for the client to do something as the `curl` above. In some languages HTTP libraries can be limiting though. (Also I would put the key in the url to make it more restful - if I understand your data correctly.)

Comment: Ok thank you very much! Actually, they are several data to send : "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}" related to the file sended (the file is in xml with a fixed format)

Comment: Might be that the clients HTTP library doesn't support multipart. Then the client could put it all in a zip or tar and send just one file instead.

Comment: Yes I think it's a good alternative.